# CreatedAtAction not respecting route template set in controller in .Net Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm working on building a restful api that returns `201 Created` when the appropriate endpoint is hit. In order to do this, I've attempted to use both the `CreatedAtAction` and the `CreatedAtRoute` methods, but they both fail to respect the route defined at the top of the controller (or at the top of the action), and instead they use the `default` route present in the `startup.cs`. If I name the route at the top of the controller, and use `CreatedAtRoute`, it will partially respect the route, but it passes the `id` field as a query string parameter instead of using it as a portion of the route (like the action specifies).

```cs
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]", Name = "Organizations")]
public class OrganizationsController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetOrganization")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetOrganization(string id)
    {
        var command = new GetOrganizationQuery(id);

        return Ok(await Mediator.Send(command));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateOrganization(CreateOrganizationCommand command)
    {
        var organization = await Mediator.Send(command);
        return CreatedAtAction("GetOrganization", "Organizations",
            new {id = organization.Id}, organization);
    }  
}
```

---

If I use:

```cs
return CreatedAtAction("GetOrganization", "Organizations", new {id = organization.Id}, organization);
// or
return CreatedAtAction("GetOrganization", new {id = organization.Id}, organization);
```

The location header is `location: https://localhost:5001/Organizations/GetOrganization/08d76ebb-95a9-ec4c-7bea-dbb5ff20cf06`.

---

If I use:

```cs
return CreatedAtRoute("GetOrganization",new {id = organization.Id}, organization);
```

I receive an error, `No route matches the supplied values.`.

---

If I use:

```cs
return CreatedAtRoute("Organizations",new {id = organization.Id}, organization);
```

I get pretty close, but the ID is added as a query string like so: `location: https://localhost:5001/api/v1/Organizations?id=08d76ebc-4b79-d9bf-32e9-3cf4202ebce7`.

If I try to make the ID an optional parameter on the controller, it gets appended to all actions within the controller, and that is also not a viable solution.

What is the proper approach to get the location to be set to the correct route?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that the root of the error is actually the `ApiVersion` being present in the route. Even though the application is setup to have `AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified` set to true, that value does not appear to affect internal routing. In order to get the application to pick up the proper route, I have to specify the api version in the `CreatedAtAction` method like the following:

```cs
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class OrganizationsController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetOrganization(string id)
    {
        var command = new GetOrganizationQuery(id);

        return Ok(await Mediator.Send(command));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateOrganization(CreateOrganizationCommand command, ApiVersion version)
    {
        var organization = await Mediator.Send(command);
        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetOrganization),
            new { id = organization.Id, version = version.ToString() }, 
            organization);
    }  
}
```

You can see more [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/409).